# How to write generic Java API without method Overloading

Tags: java, design-patterns, variadic-functions, overloading, generic-programming

I have 2 (or more), datasources which store the same thing; and I want to write an interface with methods to find items in them. Example:

```
public interface CarFinder {    
    public Car findById(String id);
}
```

Then I can write a class like this and use it:

```
public class CustomCarFinder implements CarFinder {

    public Car findById(String id) {
        ...
        return someCar;
    }
}
...
Car aCar = customCarFinder.findById("1");
```

`CustomCarFinder` knows how to connect to the datasource and retrieve the `Car` for me.
The problem is that whereas for my first datasource, the `CustomCarFinder` can get a connection to it every time I call "`findById`"; for the second datasource it is the client to the `CarFinder` that knows how to get the connection, not the `CarFinder`. To supply the connection information to `CarFinder` I wrote something like this:

```
public interface CarFinder {

    public Car findById(String id, Object... context);

}

public class CustomCarFinder implements CarFinder {

    public Car findById(String id, Object... context) {
        //The Varargs (context) are not used in this version
        ...
        return someCar;
    }
}

public class AnotherCustomCarFinder implements CarFinder {

    public Car findById(String id, Object... context) {
        //Extract the connection here from the Varargs
        CustomConnection connection = (CustomConnection)context[0];
        ...
        //Somehow I find the car via this CustomConnection thing
        return someCar;
    }
}
...
Car aCar = customCarFinder.findById("1");
Car anotherCar = anotherCustomCarFinder.findById("1", aCustomConnection);
```

You see I used varargs so that I can use either or version of the API. In the first case where the connection does not have to be supplied I can still use:

```
Car aCar = customCarFinder.findById("1");
```

and if I need to supply the connection then:

```
Car anotherCar = anotherCustomCarFinder.findById("1", aCustomConnection);
```

The Finder classes are implemented as Spring singletons, so they are shared, and so to avoid threading issues they are stateless so I don't want to set a "Connection" before using the methods; and that is why I am passing the Connection as Varargs.

Is there another way of doing the same thing? 
I am getting pushback ( from colleagues ), on the use of Varargs, that I should just overload the "`findById`" method with the different types of Connection types. 
I am resisting this, because I don't want the interface to reflect the types of datasources I am connecting to. I want the interface, if at all possible to remain:

```
public Car findById(String id);
```

I also don't like the Varargs, but I am not sure how to get rid of them and still accomplish what I want.

Comment: Any reason you can't have your custom connection as a property of your finder?

Comment: Joe, I just updated the question mentioning this: "The Finder classes are implemented as Spring singletons, so they are shared, and so to avoid threading issues they are stateless so I don't want to set a "Connection" before using the methods; and that is why I am passing the Connection as Varargs."

Answer (score 2):

Varargs are fine when they are needed, though in this case I think it would be better to have a setter for the connection.

To make this shareable across threads you can use

```
public class AnotherCustomCarFinder implements CarFinder {
    private Pool<CustomConnection> connectionPool;

    public void setConnectionPool(Pool<CustomConnection> connectionPool) {
        this.connectionPool = connectionPool;
    }

    public Car findById(String id) {
        CustomConnection connection = connectionPool.acquire();
        //Somehow I find the car via this CustomConnection thing
        connectionPool.release(connection);
        return someCar;
    }
}
```

this way you can write

```
Car aCar = customCarFinder.findById("1");
Car anotherCar = anotherCustomCarFinder.findById("1");
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that the Finder classes are Spring singletons, and they are shared so I can't really set a "global" connection, as another thread might set the connection while other methods are running that depend on another connection. So we were passing the connection per method call to avoid threading issues, synchronization, etc. So the Finders are stateless.

Comment: @GustavoT while that sounds great, the problem is your caller need to understand the working of the Finder to know what, if anything you need to provide it. If you have a global pool of connections, you could pass that instead of an individual one per thread.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no pool. The 2nd datasource is a weird source, that makes a context available when someone calls a REST API it provides. A connection can only be obtained from that Context from inside the API call ( they provide a plugin method where you can insert yourself in the API call ). So connections are available on a call to call basis; they cannot be pooled or cached; as soon as the REST call is over the connection is dead.

Comment: @GustavoT So you need a `Supplier<CustomConnection>` which should be easy to write.

Answer (score 0):

*I assume that you can use Java 8.*

If you dont like Varargs, you can pass a `Supplier` to the method instead, like this:

```
interface CarFinder {
    Car findById(String id, Supplier<Object> sup);
}

class CustomCarFinder implements CarFinder {
    public Car findById(String id, Supplier<Object> sup) {
        // ignore the sup
        // and the rest
    }
}

class AnotherCustomCarFinder implements CarFinder {
    public Car findById(String id, Supplier<Object> sup) {
        CustomConnection conn = (CustomConnection)sup.get();
        // and the rest
    }
}
```

Now you can use them:

```
customCarFinder.findById("1", () -> null);
anotherCustomCarFinder.findById("1", () -> customConnection);
```

If you also dont like `null` (I guess) you can pass a `dummyConnection`.